# Sorting table rows in jsp using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to drag and drop the rows of table. I am using jquery sorter for this. 
It is allowing me to drag the row but its not placing it on desired location. if i leave the row its returning back to its original location.

jsp

```
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" id="diagnosis_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Demand id</th>
                <th>itemCode</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach var="Demand" items="${Demand}">


            <tbody>
                <tr id="tr<%=count%>">
                    <td class="sorter"></td>
                    <td>${Demand.id}</td>
                    <td>${Demand.demandId}</td>
                    <td>${Demand.itemCode}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <%
                count = count + 1;
            %>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#diagnosis_list tbody").sortable();
    $("#diagnosis_list tbody").disableSelection();
});
```

I really dont know where i am going wrong. I was referring jquery website for this. Does any know the answer. Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: That might be a css issue as i have no issues with your markup posted, can you post a working demo where you are getting this issue?

Comment: i am working on eclips and i am running the webapp on apache 7. server

Comment: you mean to post entire project

Comment: hahaha! not really but a sample markup as the one generated you can copy/paste, that is really simple if you use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i am sorry i am new here so i dont know how to do it.

Comment: it is working fine on jsfiddle.net but for some reason it is not working in my project

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hh1gzc9e/5/ this is the link

Comment: any console error in your browser when you run at your webserver?

Comment: no. it is allowing me to drag the row. but when i leave the row it is going back to its original position

Comment: maybe if you move the `<c:forEach var="Demand" items="${Demand}">` inside the <body> tag would help you. This created multiple body tags for the table and the `sortable` extension cannot handle it. Iam pretty sure thats the problem

Comment: ohhhh. thank you so much. i will try it right away.

Comment: yup that worked. Thank you so much MaVRoSCy. I am really greatfull. I was trying to work this out since morning. Thank you

Comment: ok, i will post it as the answer and you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the

```
<c:forEach var="Demand" items="${Demand}">
```

inside the `< body >` tag.

As you have it, it creates multiple `< body >` tags for the table and the `sortable` extension cannot handle it.